# Reading FDF (Form Data Format) file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, fdf

I have an FDF file (along with the PDF version of it), [I'm following the documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-forms#importing-fdf-file-to-pdf)  :

```
//Loads an existing PDF document.
final PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.pdf').readAsBytesSync());

//Import the FDF into the existing form.
document.form
  .importData(File('Import.fdf').readAsBytesSync(), DataFormat.fdf);

//Save the PDF document.
File('output.pdf').writeAsBytesSync(await document.save());
```

I'm getting this error:

```
E/flutter ( 8489): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Incorrect field name.
E/flutter ( 8489): #0      PdfForm._importDataFDF.<anonymous closure> (package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/src/pdf/implementation/forms/pdf_form.dart:353:11)
E/flutter ( 8489): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
E/flutter ( 8489): #2      PdfForm._importDataFDF (package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/src/pdf/implementation/forms/pdf_form.dart:348:11)
```

Any help/guidance on how to fix this?